# Cst phased array feeding

Tags: antenna, ti-ccstudio, antenna-array

How can I feed my microstrip patch antenna with phase difference? I managed to get more directed beam but now I want to scan an area by changing directivity.

Comment: Use a longer piece of cable to add delay.

Comment: i think, one can set a phase at the port settings.